# In Google Cloud how to set Protocols and ports to "Allow all" with Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

In Google Cloud I am trying to create firewall rule with Python code. I am able to create firewall rule by specific ports for TCP/UDP protocol, ICMP in firewall rule, but I am not able to figure out how to set **Protocols and ports to "Allow all"** with Python code

```
firewall_body = {
  "name": "myrule",
  "direction": "INGRESS",
  "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/networks/yourvpc",
  "priority": 100,
  "allowed": [
    {
      ?????????????????
    },
    . . .
```

[image]

Request for help if anyone has done this with Python Code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following can help

```
"IPProtocol": "all"
```

You can view the rest equivalent by clicking on **equivalent REST** below the create button. This will help you complete your body more easily in your Python code in the future. After making your selection on UI, for example, choosing a name or selecting "Allow all", the REST request will change accordingly.

[image]